# Can't figure out cross site JSON

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

For the life of me I can't figure out the problem here. I've searched everything I could for days and still nothing. It would be great if any of you could solve this.

Basically I'm getting

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource".

Or other errors when I try changing the code. The site dynamically serves JSON data based on my profile.

> https://trackobot.com/profile/history.json?username=still-whelp-8571&token=bybhMPvw6b6Lr77aeX3Z

Here's my code at the moment:

```
$.getJSON('https://trackobot.com/profile/history.json?username=still-whelp-8571&token=bybhMPvw6b6Lr77aeX3Z', function(data) {
      console.log(data);
});
```

However I've also tried ajax methods using JSONP just to attempt a fix.

Any help would be appreciated and thank you.

Comment: If the site does not support JSONP or CORS requests, you will need to use a server-side proxy to make the request for you. As you've seen, you cannot make a cross-domain JSON request.

Comment: .getjson is just .ajax() that expects a json response. you can't do this cross-domain. You need to use JSONP, which requires that the server you're talking to support that.